# What is the significance of the assumption of "full energetic degeneracy" in this paper?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, statistical-mechanics, quantum-entanglement

I'm reading the new paper "Foundations of statistical mechanics from
symmetries of entanglement" (available on arxiv), in which the authors Deffner and Zurek note that the quantum microcanonical state of a system $S$ can be characterized as the state which is "fully energetically degenerate" with respect to its Hamiltonian $H_S$. What does this terminology mean? And where in Deffner and Zurek's argument does the assumption of "full energetic degeneracy" play a role? It's not clear to me at all where this assumption is invoked in the authors' line of reasoning.